# Random strings using asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a partial view that displays a random string on different views. How can I randomize the strings stored in arraylist or any collection and then show different news each time user requests ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class to get a random index within the list:

```
Random ran = new Random();
int randomIndex = ran.Next(myList.Length);

return myList[randomIndex];
```

Note: Since by default, `Random` uses time as a seed, and produces a pseudo-random result, if called in a closed loop, you can get the same string repeatedly.

I would say that since this is a web setting, and the same user will not reload that frequently, this should work fine for your purpose.

---

If you *are* calling `Random` often, using a static field for it can help:

```
// private field
private static Random ran = new Random();

// in a method
int randomIndex = ran.Next(myList.Length);

return myList[randomIndex];
```

Comment: Yes, I got it... deleted my answer

Comment: @Aliostad - We all sometimes answer a question without fully reading it ;)

Comment: @Oded I have three strings which I want to randomize but in most of cases random is giving same result. Can we configure it not to show previous string ?

Comment: @Sparrow create `Random ran = new Random();` once

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - You can have a static field for Random - this way you don't initialize it every time and can avoid the repetition issues.

Comment: @Oded I have already created it as static. I want that if news 1 appeared next should be news 2 or news 3 not news 1 again

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - You can store the last index that was provided and retry until you get a different one. Random means that the same number can come up repeatedly. If you has more strings such occurrences would be rarer.